# How can I create a Matrix in Report Builder with text values instead of aggregate values?

Tags: matrix, aggregate, rows, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3.0.

I have a data source in which users can select a value in a drop-down menu for one, two, or three available categories. Let's say this is cities and states. This data is stored as two fields. If I query those two fields, I get one column that shows the state category and another column that shows the city selected for each, resulting in multiple rows per record. I need to see this data on a single row.

So instead of this:

| Record ID | State | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | CA | Sacramento |
| 101 | OR | Ashland |
| 101 | WA | Seattle |
| 202 | CA | Oakland |
| 202 | OR | Portland |
| 303 | CA | Los Angeles |
| 303 | WA | Spokane |

I need it organized like this:

| Record ID | CA | OR | WA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Sacramento | Ashland | Seattle |
| 202 | Oakland | Portland |  |
| 303 | Los Angeles |  | Spokane |

I don't think I can group by Record ID because of other columns I have that go along with it and need to be distinct. I've already grouped by higher order fields.

I tried adding the State field as a Column Group in the Matrix Wizard, but it gave me an error message stating that the values must have an aggregate function.

I tried creating additional Calculated Fields and using them as the columns, but that created duplicate rows where the first row had a value under CA, the second had a value under OR, and the third had a value under WA. I then tried to hide duplicates, which kind of worked, but it gave me blank rows that were sometimes not aligned with the Record ID.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

In the Table/Matrix Wizard, I selected the SUM aggregation, and then when the report generated, I edited the expression in the City cell to be just the field reference instead of SUM. Lots of adding row groups and hiding row group columns later, I have my report.